# Changing Font via CSS using Google Fonts

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change my font from a free template I got offline. Below, you can see HTML for my list.

```
<header>
    <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo"></a></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#!/page_Home"><span></span><strong>Home Page</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_About"><span></span><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_Portfolio"><span></span><strong>Portfolio</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_Services"><span></span><strong>My Services</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_Contact"><span></span><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

Below is the CSS for the list:

```
header {
    width: 360px;
    float: left
}
#menu {
    padding-top: 122px
}
#menu > li {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 4px
}
#menu > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 54px;
    height: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    cursor: pointer
}
#menu > li > a span {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
#menu > li > a strong {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 95px 0 40px;
    height: 56px
}
#menu > li > a:hover,
#menu > li > a.active {
    color: #000
}
#menu > li > a:hover strong,
#menu > li > a.active strong {}
```

Now, I want to change font to Source Sans Pro, an import from Google. However, I couldn't get it to work. So I used default fonts instead to see if I was messing up the Google Import of the font, and that didn't work. Below, you can see my attempt to fix this:

```
#menu > li > a {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 54px;
    height: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

I've checked to see if any !important's are preventing inline styling overwrite, but there are none in any CSS style.

To summaries, I am trying to change the font using inline CSS styling but failing. Can anyone help?

Comment: There's nothing in the code presented here that indicates the use of Source Sans Pro or any external fonts. You should probably read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

Comment: In response to yourself Mike, you are correct. I should of been more clear. I want to be able to do it with default fonts first before I start doing imports. Build it up a step at a time for personal learning if you know what I mean. Sorry for not being so clear.

Comment: @CRover refer to comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

First add the `link` for the `Source Sans Pro` font you got from google in your `head`. This is gotten from google

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pr‌​o" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then in your `css` add

```
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
```

Or you can try using the `@import` google provided. In the head of your `html` add

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro');
</style>
```

and then the font-family

```
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
```

```css
header {
    width: 360px;
    float: left
}
#menu {
    padding-top: 122px
}
#menu > li {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 4px
}
#menu > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 54px;
    height: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    cursor: pointer
}
#menu > li > a span {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
#menu > li > a strong {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 95px 0 40px;
    height: 56px
}
#menu > li > a:hover,
#menu > li > a.active {
    color: #000
}
#menu > li > a:hover strong,
#menu > li > a.active strong {}
#menu > li > a {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 54px;
    height: 56px;
    color: #000;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo"></a></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#!/page_Home"><span></span><strong>Home Page</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_About"><span></span><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_Portfolio"><span></span><strong>Portfolio</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_Services"><span></span><strong>My Services</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_Contact"><span></span><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Below you can see what I attempted: HTML: http://pastebin.com/k906PkBx   CSS:  http://pastebin.com/GFX4ER7t  View line 35 for CSS changes.

Comment: You should check if you are putting the font in the right place and also make sure you are online while trying google fonts

Comment: When you mean online, you mean having internet connection correct? In regards to the location of font, I've checked and it appears to be in the right place.

Comment: I'm currently out of town but I'll be sure to try this out! Thanks for the quick response.